# Pandas: fillna every columns with some value

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe and there are `NaN` values:

```
col1   col2    col3
234    NaN     1
NaN    NaN     18
9      2       NaN
```

I have list with values [12, 15, 3] and I need to fill this columns:

Desire output

```
col1   col2   col3
234    15     1
12     15     18
9      2      3
```

I can do it with

```
for (col, mean) in zip(df.columns, means):
    df[col].fillna(mean, inplace=True)
```

But is any way to do it without loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a dict of those , then `fillna`

```
l1= [12, 15, 3]

df.fillna(dict(zip(df.columns,l1)))
Out[120]: 
    col1  col2  col3
0  234.0  15.0   1.0
1   12.0  15.0  18.0
2    9.0   2.0   3.0
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I'd probably split it in a few more lines. Anyway +1

Answer (score 4):

Yet another approach:

```
df.fillna( pd.Series( [12, 15, 3], index=df.columns ) )
```

It looks like you may want the mean of each column (?), in which case you could just do:

```
df.fillna( df.mean() )      # df.mean() returns a series
```

In any event, the key to this answer and the others is just to give some sort of labelled output to fillna.  Here I'm using a series whereas the other answers use dictionaries.  Either approach is fine, of course, just depends on which is more convenient for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your list to a dictionary and give fillna a dictionary as an argument:

```
 df.fillna({'col1': 12,'col2': 15, 'col3':3}, inplace=True)
```